# How to implement autocomplete with rich textbox in infopath2007?

Tags: .net, richtextbox, infopath

I've met a problem, our user asked me to implement autocomplete with rich textbox in infopath2007, and i've googled a lot, but failed, can anyone help me about it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd guess you will be out of luck with 2007. In 2010 you can use the SPServices and jQuery to achieve this - [see article](http://sympmarc.com/2011/08/24/using-spservices-with-jqueryuis-autocomplete-function-on-infopath-forms-in-sharepoint/)

Comment: Hi Scharf, actually what I need is this rich text box remember last input, just like single text box auto-complete function...

Comment: unfortunately the richtext box does not allow auto-complete like the normal testbox does.